# Using Dapper-dot-net, how do I map SQL Time column to a .Net type?

Tags: .net, t-sql, dapper

I have an existing database that uses the SQL `time(7)` type, which does not map directly to a .Net type.

**Question:** Using Dapper, how do I map a SQL `time` column to a .Net type?

**Issue:** When I attempt to implicitly map a SQL `time(7)` column to `DateTime` using Dapper-dot-net, I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred in
>   Dapper.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error parsing column 5
>   (CheckInTime=08:54:43.1470000 - Object)

I assumed it would map to DateTime automatically, but it does not appear to do so

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success mapping SQL time(7) columns to `System.TimeSpan`.

As Dan pointed out, a `TimeSpan` is "semantically" less appropriate if your intent is to represent a time of the day.

But I think that, technically, there is no loss of information going from time(7) to TimeSpan, so the data is there, and it's a matter of meaning.

One way I've been using to alleviate the ugliness is to use a private `TimeSpan` property just for the sake of querying and expose the data in a custom type public property.

I prefer that over using a `DateTime` in combination with the call to `CONVERT()` in the SQL, because even with the `DateTime` you still have a somehow "imperfect" representation of you data (the date part is bogus) **and** you introduce ugliness in the SQL as well.

But, at this point, I think it can be considered a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Good point! Although it probably depends on a factor I didn't mention: is the time(7) used to represent an amount of time or does it represent a time of day? If one is looking for an amount, then this is the correct method.

Comment: One could interpret a returned TimeSpan as the amount of time from midnight.

Comment: It’s 2022 now, and .NET 6 and beyond now has the `System.DateOnly` type which matches ISO SQL’s `date` type, and `System.TimeOnly` which corresponds to ISO SQL’s `time` type.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you must explicitly cast/convert the time column in T-SQL to either DateTime or TimeSpan depending on your need.

**If your time represents a time of day (i.e. 4:15pm)**

```
string sql = @"SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, InTime) AS CheckInTime FROM TimeLog";

var checkInTimes = _conn.Query<DateTime>(sql).ToList();
```

**If your time represents a nullable time of day (i.e. 4:15pm or null)**

To handle a nullable time, you just change the target .Net type to nullable (DateTime?):

```
// Note: the OutTime column is nullable
string sql = @"SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, OutTime) AS CheckOutTime FROM TimeLog";

var checkOutTimes = _conn.Query<DateTime?>(sql).ToList();
```

Note that the date part of the resulting DateTime object will be set to 1900-01-01.

**If your time represents an amount of time (i.e. 2 hours and 47 minutes running time)**

In this case it is better to convert to TimeSpan which will not include the invalid 1900 date, but also does not allow for AM/PM formatting in .ToString()

```
string sql = @"SELECT RunningTime FROM TimeLog";
var movieLength = _conn.Query<TimeSpan>(sql).ToList();
```

*Thanks to Mauro for pointing out this use case.*